# Which BT stack does Tizen support?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, tizen

I would like to know if Tizen has support for BT and if so does it use the open source bluez protocol?

Also I would like to know where to start digging when it comes to bluetooth in Tizen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need bluetooth info from a user pespective or from a tizen app developer perspective ?

Comment: I currently work in the framework, hal and kernel modules of Android. So I'm curious to know how Tizen does the same in bluetooth. It seems to use bluez as well which I was hoping for.. not an app developer really. But doesn't really make a difference to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages in tizen have bluez, checked in package list 
https://www.tizen.org/package-list 
Not sure about the version or other info

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any more information? Like where the source might be and if there is a way to test BT functionality?

Comment: http://download.tizen.org/misc/media/conference2012/wednesday/bayview/2012-05-09-0900-0940-bluez-_plugging_the_unpluggable.pdf is the ppt given by bluez team, no other info as i also searched in net

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it supports Bluetooth and it uses **bluez stack and obexd.**

Version: Bluez-4.101, Obexd-0.34

The profiles supported by Tizen Bluetooth are GAP, SDP, A2DP, AVRCP, HFP, HSP, GATT.

Obexd profiles include OPP, FTP, PBAP, SYNC, MAP

Answer (score 0):

On SamsungGear2 :

```
~/tizen-sdk/tools/sdb shell rpm -qa | grep bluez
bluez-4.101_40-8.1.rinatoxx.armv7l
```

I can also test on SamsungZ1 or tizen camera if needed